# I am getting in pspice

Tags: pspice

I am using orcad 16.6 version,

I am getting in pspice as

ERROR(ORPSIM-15108): Subcircuit TL082 used by X_U5A is undefined.

I dont know how to overcome this error.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Yep, correct the syntax of your netlist. Look at the netlist and make sure the syntax is correct

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the library file for TL0802 to your pspice simulation?

TI has a decent tutorial on how to do this here: [Link](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa070/sloa070.pdf)